# How to view PDF or DOC file in Browser without <iframe> tag

Tags: html, iframe

I am using HTML with JSF application in my project and also used ClickJack filter option. First I try iFrame, Object, embed for view pdf portion. I refer path in tomcat folder

```
<iframe src="/path/file.pdf"/>
```

at the time browser to show error message is **To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, 
the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.**.
So I need any other way to display pdf or doc file in browser is possible?

Comment: Is it possible for you to open it in a new tab like this? `<a href="/path/file.pdf" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>`

Comment: I need to view microsoft office file also. Is there any js option to view document file is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, Edge, and other modern browsers can read PDF files within the browser natively. If you use a link like so:

```
<a href="your-pdf-file-location.pdf">My PDF</a>
```

It should open a window like this:

[image]

Comment: In mozilla and IE 11 click the llink to it will downloaded.If I need click to view means what steps to follow?